# Problemas acceso a WS de SOAP desde Java: WSDLException: faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper y java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java, xml, soap, certificado-ssl, soapui

Estoy trantando llamar desde mi aplicación Java a un Webservice de Soap de la siguiente manera:

```
@Override
    public String getLoginServiciosGeneral() throws Exception {
        String idSesion = "";
        try{
            LoginServiciosGeneralService service = new LoginServiciosGeneralService(new URL("https://XXXXXX.es/services/ws/LoginServiciosGeneral?wsdl"));
            
            LoginServiciosGeneralPortType port = service.getLoginServiciosGeneral();
            
            idSesion = port.loginServiciosGeneral("prueba");
            System.out.println("hasta aca");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("MalformedURLException. Problemas en la llamada al servicio loginServiciosGeneral, motivo: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception. Problemas en la llamada al servicio loginServiciosGeneral, motivo: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        
    return idSesion;
    }
```

Donde **LoginServiciosGeneralService** es una clase de tipo *@WebServiceCliente* y **LoginServiciosGeneralPortType** es de *@WebService*

Justo donde se declara la variable service me da el siguiente error:

> Exception. Problemas en la llamada al servicio loginServiciosGeneral,
> motivo: The following WSDL exception occurred: WSDLException:
> faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper : : javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException:
> faultCode=WSDL4JWrapper : : java.net.ConnectException: Connection
> timed out: connect

Por lo que ve es salta en el catch **Exception**.

En la herramienta **Soap** accedo sin problemas, pero en Java no. La URL de acceso pertenece a un Ministerio el cual contiene un certificado con firma con sus dos ficheros: uno publico de extensión **.cer** y uno privado de extensión **.p12** y su **contraseña** para acceder.

Me gustaría saber cómo utilizar el certificado en Java para poder acceder a la URL y que me devuelva datos. También me gustaría saber si el **timeout** que me devuelve tiene que ver con **Proxy**.

Estos son los parametros de entrada en SOAP:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ent="https://xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
      <ent:LoginServiciosGeneralIn>
       prueba
      </ent:LoginServiciosGeneralIn>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Utilizo la **versión 8** de Java, no tengo permiso para utilizar una versión superior.

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo.

Comment: veo algo difícil de reproducir tu escenario, espero alguien tenga tiempo y disposición de intentarlo.

Comment: He añadido los parámetros del SOAP. Pero si necesitas más información no dudes en pedirlo.